# EncryptedSharedPreferences destroyed when same SharedUserId

Tags: android, keystore

I distribute 2 apps in the Play Store: a Free and a Pro variant.
When you buy the Pro, the app settings are transferred from the Free to the Pro and the Free is deleted.

Recently I've been using EnryptedSharedPreferences to store passwords securely.

As soon as you install the Pro (no need to start the app), the keystore of the Free is "destroyed" (javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException). You can neither read nor write to it in the Free.
This causes that the passwords can't be read from the Free and transferred to the Pro anymore.

If I use different "android:sharedUserId" it does not occur. However, I need this to exchange data between the apps.

Is there another way so that each app can use its own EncryptedSharedPreferences?

Comment: The sharedUserId may work, but AFAIR it is deprecated. If you want to transfer encrypted data between apps but key is bound to one app you can only decrypt the data and reencryot the data in the target app.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, after installing the target app, it is no longer possible to decrypt the data in the source app.

Comment: Could be because of the sharedUserId setting, or the Pro app reinitializes the cryptographic keys and thus overwrites the keys from the Free version. A better way to transfer data from Free to pro would be a signature restricted content provider.